# avformat code produce slightly different output than ffmpeg with same parameters - why?

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec, libavformat

I would like to achieve the exact same result as this ffmpeg command line call does from code:

```
ffmpeg -i CAMERARTSPLINK -c:v copy -an -movflags +frag_keyframe+empty_moov -f mp4
```

When I run the above command it gives this binary result:

```
got 36 bytes:  0, 0, 0, 36, 102, 116, 121, 112, ..., 111, 54, 109, 112, 52, 49, 
got 512 bytes: 0, 0, 3, 76, 109, 111, 111, 118, 0, 0, 0, ..., 132, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 3, 0, 202,
```

The code can utilize ffmpeg libraries and includes, but I don't want to use ffmpeg as a program call (i.e. exec* functions are not preferred).

I have created a small demonstration code example with `avformat` for an RTSP H264 to MP4 remux.
The code is highly reuses horgh's nice [videostreamer](https://github.com/horgh/videostreamer) library.

I posted the [sample code](https://pastebin.com/7aYKREtW) to pastebin.com (400 loc). It builds successfully but you need to link it against `avformat`, `avdevice`, `avcodec` and `avutil`.

I tried to do my best to reach the same result, however when I run this code, the first few bytes after byte #38 are different (maybe not just those, I did not compare anything after byte #548):

```
writeOutput: writing 36 bytes: 0, 0, 0, 36, 102, 116, 121, 112, ..., 111, 54, 109, 112, 52, 49, 
writeOutput: writing 512 bytes: 0, 0, 0, 0, 109, 111, 111, 118, 0, 0, 0, ..., 132, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 3, 0, 202,
```

You can see on the second line of my code's output starts with `0` `0` **`0` `0`** `109`,

whereas the ffmpeg gave `0` `0` **`3` `76`** `109`.

All the rest (even the bytes are not pasted here) data are totally the same (at least for the first 548 bytes).

What is wrong with my code? These 2 bytes seems super-important for decoding this stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a silly mistake of ffmpeg's limited logging functionality plus my limited knowledge in video codecs.

The problem was that ffmpeg (with h264 input) when writes an atom to the output buffer:

- first puts 0 for the atom's size ([movenc.c#L3981](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/movenc.c#L3981))
- then fills the rest of the buffer
- then at the end it seeks back to atom's size in buffer and update the size ([movenc.c#L4049](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/movenc.c#L4049))

This is all good, but during filling the rest of the buffer, it uses [avio_w8](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.7/aviobuf_8c_source.html#l00155) and avio_w8 **will flush the buffer**, if it reaches the end of it.

If you are using custom IO with `avio_alloc_context` AND you don't define a buffer which is large enough AND you don't define the seek operation either AND the atom being written is larger than your buffer size, it will be flushed out and ffmpeg will not be able to seek back to update the atom's size.

And this will probably result in a corrupted (and unplayable) video output file or stream.

So the solution was to increase the buffer size from 512 to 4096 in this case moov atom can be fit even without seeking operation.

This is pretty straightforward if you know that the moov atom is larger that 512 bytes in length and look my sample code.

Answer (score 1):

`102, 116, 121, 112` in ascii is `ftyp` This is the mp4 format type box. `0, 0, 0, 36` is the size of the box

`109, 111, 111, 118` in ascii is `mdat` This is the data box. `0, 0, 0, 0` is the size of the box.

In this case the size of the `mdat` box is unknown because we don't know the size of all the video and audio frames yet. So a placeholder of zero is used. When the file is finished the size value should be overwritten with the correct size

Comment: thanks. makes sense. however ffmpeg command is not outputting to file, it goes directly to stdout. so no way that it can change the size of the box after once it printed to stdout. How can I achieve the same with avformat?

Comment: what I need: avformat must not print the mdat box until its size is not known

Comment: i.e. in my custom io callback there is no seek function defined.

Comment: or, to reverse the question: how ffmpeg knows the mdat's size (at the time of printing to stdout) and my code is not?

Comment: Ffmpeg can’t know the size of the mdat box before it’s written. Writing an mp4 to standard out  is not a valid operation. You must either use a fragmented mp4 or a another streamable container like mkv.

Comment: my ffmpeg command creates fragmented mp4, because it uses 'frag_keyframe'. This option is also added to my code. So, ffmpeg when creates fmp4 knows the mdat's size, but my code is not.

Comment: Are you sure? Can you check the rest of the file for moof’s?

Comment: I don't know what to check, but here is the analysis of thumb.co.il: https://imgur.com/a/ScPiOai (this is the stdout from ffmpeg commandline above written to file)

Comment: Oh, and i think you are not correct: `109, 111, 111, 118` in ascii is `moov`.

Comment: I know 109, 111, 111, 118 is moov. That’s why I am asking about moof.

Comment: You wrote "109, 111, 111, 118 in ascii is mdat This is the data box. 0, 0, 0, 0 is the size of the box.". Moof: i linked an image which contains the moof but dont know what to see in there :(